# How to checked true extjs treepanel checkbox on button click programatically?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I have an Extjs treepanel to which I have added a number of layers. Also, I have a search panel containing a search button. When search button is clicked, it returns the results in a extjs gridview.

I want to show layers by clicking on gridviews row and set checkbox of treepanel to true either dynamically or programatically
I have added tree panel like

```
var layerTree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    border: true,
    root: layerList,
    split: true,
    containerScroll: true,
    collapseMode: "mini",
    autoScroll: true,
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        applyLoader: false,
        uiProviders: {
            "layernodeui": LayerNodeUI
        }
    }),
    root: {
        nodeType: "async",
        children: Ext.decode(treeConfig)
    },
    listeners: {
        "radiochange": function(node) {}
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false

});
```

And I want like `layernode.checked=true`

Thanks Akatum You said

In your grid configuration you need to setup listener for itemclick event, which is fired when user click on row in grid. In this listener you need to get information about layer from row record. Then you can find layer node in tree by Ext.data.TreeStore getNodeById method and set its checked attribute to true

So in your grid configuration you will have:

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(c, record) {
        // get layer id from clicked row record
        var layerId = record.get('layerId');

        // find layer node in tree by layer id
        var node = layerTree.getStore().getNodeById(layerId);

        // set node checked attribute to true
        node.set('checked', true);
    }
}
```

I tried your code but its not working. I have added your suggested code in my code like this

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
     store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
         fields: action.result.fields,
         listeners: {
             load: function() {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
                 }, 100);
             }
         }
     }),
     frame: true,
     columns: action.result.columns,
     stripeRows: true,
     listeners: {
         itemclick: function(c, record) {
             var layerId = record.get('layerId');
             var node = layerTree.getStore().getNodeById(layerId);
             node.set('checked', true);
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your grid configuration you need to setup listener for [`itemclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick) event, which is fired when user click on row in grid. In this listener you need to get information about layer from row record. Then you can find layer node in tree by `Ext.data.TreeStore` [`getNodeById`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-getNodeById) method and set its checked attribute to `true`

So in your grid configuration you will have:

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(c, record) {
        // get layer id from clicked row record
        var layerId = record.get('layerId');

        // find layer node in tree by layer id
        var node = layerTree.getStore().getNodeById(layerId);

        // set node checked attribute to true
        node.set('checked', true);
    }
}
```